# Out of range index in if condition

Tags: c#, for-loop, exception

I have a sentence, and I want to check for *duplication letters* in order to add a `'x'` as a separator between them, however I debugged and kept getting an exception in here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
{
    t += res[i];

    if (res[i] == res[i + 1]) //Index out of range exception here
    {
        t += 'x';
    }
}
```

what goes wrong in here?

Comment: when `i == res.Length - 1` you have `res[i + 1]` being `res[res.Length]` which throws exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i+1 us causing this.

in the last iteration, i+1 refers to a location which is not inside that array.

Better change the condition in for loop as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < res.Length - 1; i++)
{
    t += res[i];

    if (res[i] == res[i + 1]) //Index out of range exception here
    {
        t += 'x';
    }
}

t += res[res.Length -1 ];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: worked out, thanks

Comment: Not the correct answer, but good luck anyway.

Comment: It seems that the *last character* will not be *added* .

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne - i agree that last character would not be added, i will update the full code here, but the question was mainly about the out of index exception, I believe that this answers the question.

Comment: It doesn't, though, does it? Because you've given birth to another problem. If you change the for, `t += res[i];` will never occur for the last element.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of misbehavior is in the `if`:

```
  if (res[i] == res[i + 1])
```

when `i == res.Length - 1` (`for` loop last iteration) you have

```
  if (res[res.Length - 1] == res[res.Length])
```

and `res[res.Length]` throws `OutOfRangeException` since valid range is `[0..res.Length - 1]` (please, note `- 1`).

Your code corrected:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
    {
        Nplaintext += res[i];
        // we don't want to check (and insert 'x') for the last symbol
        if (i < res.Length - 1 && res[i] == res[i + 1]) 
        {
            Nplaintext += 'x';
        }
    }
```

Often we work with `string` with a help of *regular expressions* (let .Net loop over the `string` for you):

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = "ABBBACCADBCAADA";

  // Any symbol followed by itself should be replaced with the symbol and 'x'
  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(.)(?=\1)", "$1x");

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  ABxBxBACxCADBCAxADA
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally, someone with a brain. Too many answers suggesting to change the for to `Length - 1`, completely unaware that nothing will happen with the last element of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you get this exception. In the case i=res.Length -1 (what is exactly the last position) you ask for res[Length] with the i +1 but because of starting with 0 the element you are asking for does not exist.
try something like

```
if(i+i < res.Length)
```

before you ask for that element
or even better start counting with i=1 and use

```
if (res[i] == res[i - 1]) 
        {
            Nplaintext += 'q';
        }
```